# testing session controller for facebook authentication in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, omniauth-facebook

I have basic facebook authentication in place in my ruby on rails app. I have followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast tutorial.

I am trying to write unit specs for the session_controller which handles communication with Facebook server.
Here's how my controller looks like:

```
def create
 user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
 session[:user_id] = user.id
 redirect_to root_url
end

def destroy
 sign_out
 redirect_to root_url
end

private
 def sign_in(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
 end

 def sign_out
  session[:user_id] = nil
  @current_user = nil
 end
```

and my spec is like this:

```
it 'should set session variable and redirect to root path' do

  get :create
  expect(session[:user_id].present?).to eq true
  expect(response).to be_success
  expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)

end
```

end

but with this setup I 'm getting following error 
`Failure/Error: get :create
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"`

I have added following things to my routes.rb file

`match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get]`

Any solution folks? Btw just extention to this, Is it really necessary to test this part of code ? As this must be taken care by third party gem developers.